# Only show Date() text after explicitly stating it

Tags: swiftui

The goal here is to show `Select a start time` until the user clicks the button, toggling the `DatePicker`. Once a date is picked, the `DatePicker` is untoggled and the result is now shown where `Select a start time` was shown.

I'm working with the following code:

```swift
Button(action: {
    if self.end_time_toggle == true {
        self.end_time_toggle.toggle()
    }
    self.start_time_toggle.toggle()
}) {
    if self.start_time_toggle == true {
        DatePicker("Select a start time", selection: $create_event_vm.start_time, in: Date()...)
            .labelsHidden()
            .frame(width: 290, height: 80, alignment: .center)
            .clipped()
    }
    else if self.create_event_vm.start_time != Date() {
        Text("\(self.create_event_vm.start_time, formatter: self.time_formatter)")
            .foregroundColor(Color("grey4"))
            .scaledFont(name: "Gotham Book", size: 18)
            .fixedSize()
    }
    else {
        Text("Select a start time")
            .foregroundColor(Color("grey4"))
            .scaledFont(name: "Gotham Book", size: 18)
            .fixedSize()
    }
}
```

The problem with what I currently have is that it never shows `Select a start time` and instead shows the current date that is initialized alongside the `Date()` object that is set within my `create_event_vm`, which looks like this:

```swift
@Published var start_time: Date = Date()
```

Comment: please read and consider https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example